# sizeof array in a struct C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm trying to access the whole array from a struct in a function, to compare two elements for no duplication. However, I am receiving an `expected expression error` in `queue.id[]`.

```
int count = sizeof(queue.id[]) / sizeof(queue.id[0]);
```

Comment: To complete this question please show us i detail how `queue` is defined. As it stands this question can not clearly be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int count = sizeof(queue.id[]) / sizeof(queue.id[0]);
```

should be

```
int count = sizeof(queue.id) / sizeof(queue.id[0]);
```

Comment: Invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'int[]'

Comment: `sizeof` is used to get the size of a thing at compile time, but a trailing `int[]` in a struct is specifically used when the size is unknown at compile time. You can't use `sizeof` here.